# Angular 6: Why is child component template rendered twice?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component

I have two Angular components app-image-input and app-button. I use app-button in the template for app-image-input as follows.

**AppButtonComponent**

appButton.html

```html
<button type="button" (click)="buttonClicked.emit()">{{label}}</button>
```

appButton.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './appButton.html'
})
export class AppButtonComponent {

  @Input()
  label : string

  @Input()
  enabled : boolean

  @Output()
  buttonClicked = new EventEmitter()
}
```

**AppImageInputComponent**

appImageInput.html

```html
<div class="take-photo">
  <span>Photo</span><input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
</div>

<hr class="hr">

<div class="inner">
    <app-button class="submit" label="Submit" (buttonClicked)="submitClk()"></app-button>
    <app-button label="Cancel" (buttonClicked)="cancelClk()"></app-button>
</div>
```

**AppModule**

app.module.ts

```js
// ..... imports go here.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppButtonComponent, AppImageInputComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppButtonComponent, AppImageInputComponent],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { 
  ngDoBootstrap() {
  }

  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    Array.from(new Map<Type<any>, string>([
      [AppButtonComponent, 'app-button'],
      [AppImageInputComponent, 'app-image-input'],
      ]), ([key, value]) => {
      customElements.define(value, createCustomElement(key, {injector}))
    })
  }
}
```

**Problem**
I package my app as angular elements and use in vanilla HTML/JS app. The weird behavior I am encountering has to do with the way I use my image input component.

If I do the following, I get an image component as expected.

```html
<body>
  <app-image-input></app-image-input>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

However, when I do the following, buttons are duplicated.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => {
      var elem = document.createElement("app-image-input");
      document.body.appendChild(elem);
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

*Please note that setting the timeout to something around 400 (instead of 1000) millisecs gives the correct output!!*

You can find complete project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YLxE6BG6I7WIyR3vQp1wfYwBEjnHdD97/view?usp=sharing).

Also, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mgv3c thanks to [Caramiriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688785/caramiriel)

Comment: Where I can reproduce the issue? Stackblitzz?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt feedback. I will try to setup something online now.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I update the question with full source code. I got some exception on Stackblitzz which I am trying to workout in the meantime.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with *order* and  timing of customElements defining and using them in the dom.

Comment: StackBlitz, because I have too much time: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4mgv3c

Comment: You can't mix plain JS and Angular, at lest not like this. Better do all in angular, or use Angular NgZone thingie (but this is a road to hell, really).

Comment: In other words, Angular wants to control whole DOM, no manipulations should come from outside (except user interactions, of course). And you effectively mess with DOM in unexpected (to Angular) manner, and don't even notify it about your changes. As for the delay, that's probably total time needed for Angular to load and initialize, so, if you make it before Angular kicks in, it works. But that's very unreliable, as you can see.

Comment: @Caramiriel many thanks for your help. I was getting some typeerror.

Comment: @alx I thought that Angular Custom Elements is built for purpose that packaging  angular components to be used outside Angular. Unfortunately, I have to components outside angular ... any pointers?

Comment: Alright, so it seems that its acting up if the element is already registered. I suspect that it's rendering the element through angular once, and then again through the custom element. Changing the registration to `customElements.define('ex-app-image-input', createCustomElement(AppImageInputComponent, {injector: this.injector}))` for example, will get around that issue. Anyone can confirm and post as an actual answer?

Comment: @Caramiriel yeah it seems so to me. I don't really understand your change. Can you explain more and I will try it now.

Comment: Came to the same conclusion as @Caramiriel -- renaming element helped. Sorry for confusion, I thought custom elements were not supported in Angular 6 yet.

Comment: I still cannot get it to work, can you please elaborate on the fix.

Comment: Okay, now it works, changing app-button to ex-app-button. If you can post an answer I can mark it as accepted. Anyways, thank you both.

Comment: Why do you even need `customElements.define('app-button', 
      createCustomElement(AppButtonComponent, {injector}));` it looks unnecesary?

Comment: @Xesenix I need to use Angular Custom Elements to create components elements through vanilla JS.

Comment: @SamerMakary I mean you dont need that particular part so that it works correctly and without it there is no bug related to multiple buttons
check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ygryjo

Comment: @SamerMakary, NOT use appendChild to add a component in angular! In angular, to append dinamically a component you use ViewContainerRef and ComponentFactoryResolver, see an example in the doc: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. else your component can not work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it's rendered as an Angular component and it's also rendered as an web component too. Hence, you see it twice. Just use an custom element name that does not match the app's selector, so that you can decide whether to render the custom element version or the Angular component version.